MongoDB CRUD Nextjs Delete request not working
I'm trying to delete topic but it's not working. id is complete empty i think but still can't solve this.
It's my app/api/topics/[id]/route.js
import connectMongoDB from "@/lib";
import Topic from "@/models/topic";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


// PUT: Update a topic by id
export async function PUT(request, { params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  console.log("Received id:", id); // Log the id to ensure it's correct
  const {
    newType: type,
    newTitle: title,
    newDescription: description,
  } = await request.json();

  try {
    await connectMongoDB();
    const updatedTopic = await Topic.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      { title, description, type },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!updatedTopic) {
      return NextResponse.error(new Error("Topic not found"), { status: 404 });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ topic: updatedTopic }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating topic:", error);
    return NextResponse.error(new Error("Failed to update topic"), {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}



// DELETE: Delete a topic by id
export async function DELETE(request, { params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  if (!id) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "ID is required" }), { status: 400, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
  }

  try {
      await connectMongoDB();
      const deletedTopic = await Topic.findByIdAndDelete(id);
      if (!deletedTopic) {
          return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Topic not found" }), { status: 404, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
      }
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Topic deleted" }), { status: 200, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error deleting topic:", error);
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Error deleting topic" }), { status: 500, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
  }
}



and it's my fetchData Add Remove func
useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get('/api/topics');
                    console.log('Fetched topics:', response.data.topics); 
                    const fetchedTopics = response.data.topics.map((topic: { _id: string; title: string; type: string; description: string }) => ({
                        id: topic._id,  
                        title: topic.title,
                        type: topic.type,
                        description: topic.description,
                    }));
                    setTopics(fetchedTopics);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching topics:', error);
                }
            };
            fetchData();
        }, []);

         const handleAddTodo = async (editedBlog: { title: string; type: string; description: string }) => {
            try {
                
                const response = await axios.post('/api/topics', editedBlog);
                const createdTopic = response.data.topic;
                setTopics(prevTopics => [...prevTopics, { ...createdTopic, id: createdTopic._id }]);
                setDescription('');
                setType('');
                setTitle('');
                console.log(createdTopic)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error adding or updating todo:', error);
            }
        };
        const handleRemoveTodo = async (_id:string) => {
            if (!_id) {
                console.error('Error: ID is empty.');
                return;
            }
            
            try {
                console.log(`Deleting topic with id: ${_id}`);
                await axios.delete(`/api/topics/${topic.id}`);
                setTopics(prevTopics => prevTopics.filter(topic => topic.id !== _id));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error deleting topic:', error);
            }
        };
    
        const handleRemoveAndClose = () => {
            if (editedBlog && editedBlog.id) {
                handleRemoveTodo(editedBlog.id);
                setSelectedBlogIndex(null);
                onClose();
            }
        };


And it is Modal that remove edit button exist
{isOpen && selectedBlogIndex !== null && (
                <Modal backdrop='blur' scrollBehavior='inside' isOpen={true} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} onClose={onClose} placement='center'>
                    <ModalContent >
                        <div >
                            <ModalHeader >
                                {/* <select value={editedBlog?.type || "Backlog"} onChange={(e) => setEditedBlog({ ...editedBlog, type: e.target.value })} ">
                                    <option value="Backlog">Backlog</option>

                                </select> */}
                            </ModalHeader>
                            {/* <div className='w-full p-5'>
                                <select value={editedBlog?.title || ""} onChange={(e) => setEditedBlog({ ...editedBlog, title: e.target.value })}>
                                    <option value="">Select your title</option>
                                    <option value="Banner">Banner</option>
                                    
                                </select>
                            </div> */}
                            <ModalBody >
                                {/* <div>
                                        <textarea
                                            value={editedBlog?.description || ""}
                                            onChange={(e) => setEditedBlog({ ...editedBlog, description: e.target.value })}
                                        />
                                    </div> */}
                            </ModalBody>
                            <ModalFooter>
                                {/* <Button  onClick={() => handleEditBlog(editedBlog)}> */}
                                Save Changes
                                {/* </Button> */}
                                <Button className="p-2 rounded-2xl w-auto bg-blue-500 text-white                 border-0 outline-none hover:bg-blue-400" onPress={onClose}>
                                    Close
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    onClick={() => {
                                       console.log(`Attempting to delete topic with id:           ${topic.id}`); // Debugging log
                                        handleRemoveTodo(topic.id);
                                    }}>
                                     Remove
                                 </Button>

                            </ModalFooter>
                        </div>
                    </ModalContent>
                </Modal>

Please help guys. I stuck on this so long time. and the error says my topic.id is empty :
Refresh\] done in 1408ms
CardBacklog.tsx:93 Attempting to delete topic with id:
app-index.tsx:25 Error: ID is empty.

"as you can see its just debug"

Shouldn't your DELETE method be in a file named app/api/topics/[id]/route.js? See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments

My bad It is in that path. Edited

Why are you using topic.id in the request instead of _id (in handleRemoveTodo())?

I don't know man. My brain fully stopped. I tried to take _id from mongodb into my code as id. I thought i can use _id as id and handleAddTodo(topic.id)

I'm not talking about the way you call it. Look at the code inside handleRemoveTodo. It accepts an argument named _id which you validate and log (ie console.log(\Deleting topic with id: ${_id}`)) but then you make the request using axios.delete(`/api/topics/${topic.id}`)`

What should I do? Please help me :(

I would have expected axios.delete(\/api/topics/${_id}`)`

Ah I see.I tried that too. Actually.       handleRemoveTodo = async (id:string) => {
if (!id) {
console.error('Error: ID is empty.');
return;
}
        try {
            await axios.delete(`/api/topics/${id}`);
            setTopics(prevTopics => prevTopics.filter(topic => topic.id !== id));
        } 
    };    It's my 1st code before I get lost.


As someone has already downvoted, I think you're going to have a rough time here, but you know, you have not mentioned enough useful information; still let me help you out a little bit.

The first issue is your client-end params. You should be using You should follow the best practice and use await axios.delete(`/api/topics?id=${id}`);. The ID should be coming from the /app/.../[id]/route.js page. [id] is mapped as router query in NextJS, so you just have to grab it client-side using router.query or useSearchParams based on your 'use client' or 'use server' page.

Make sure to console.log before you handleDelete, check for the ID you're passing, why the debug line is not getting the id, maybe you're missing the ID property or clicking the handleDelete before the ID is even present there. Let me know, I might help.



oh thank you man. I am still stuck on this can you still available for help me?

I can. Let me know more briefly.
